# google app script new IDE manage deployments and new deployments all hang shows loading for ever

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, deployment, ide

I started using the new IDE and was working but all of a sudden the deployment option shows loading and sits there no error message.  No longer functional to deploy.

I have restarted browser, same issue , switched to legacy (which works fine),  back to new IDE and it hangs.    It is now unusable.

A different script project I can get it to load but it has no deployments.

Has anyone seen this issue

Comment: I think that's something I'd report as an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B)

Comment: The issue resolved itself,  I did nothing to fix it.   I used legacy for a few days and went back to the new editor and now its fine.   looks like an outage to me.

Comment: I had a similar problem yesterday.  In the morning I couldn't create new triggers in my main account but by evening it was working againt.  And overall I like the new editor although sometimes the helper screens kind of get in your way and you have to keep typing escaping to let some of the context sensitive help to dominate and help lead the way.

Answer (score 0):

issue fixed itself,  no action on my part,   seems like this was an outage of some kind.